# Standard error of regression coefficients for a transformed regressand in python

Tags: python, regression, uncertainty

I'm using python curvefit to fit a multi-variable regression. The regressand is transformed using square root transformation. While it was direct to back-transform the coefficients , I was not sure how is standard error of coefficients calculated in curve fit and if the errors were calculated for coefficients with a transformed regress and, how can they be interpreted when the coefficents are back-transformed.

For example y = ax^b is my regression function where y is transformed using a square root function. Y0 is the original observation and y is y0^(0.5).

I have coefficients a and b from the regression. Then writing the same for y0, 
y0 = (ax^b)^(1/0.5) which is y0 = a0(x^(1/0.5))^b0
where a0  = a^(1/0.5) and b0 = b/0.5

Now how can I do the same for pcov in curvefit such that I know the uncertainty in a0 and b0 ?

Also how can I do this transformation for coefficeints when the function is y = a(x-c)^b?